# VS2012 Project Linker Error

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012 Ultimate with the Project Linker extension. When I right click on a project and select Add project link..., I get this error popover.

[image: error]

If I hit "Ignore", the correct dialog box opens and I am able to successfully link the project.

Anyone have a clue as to what this error means?

Comment: Click on the [Q and A tab](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/273dbf44-55a1-4ac6-a1f3-0b9741587b9a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assertion failed error occurs when a condition (specified by assertion statement) does not hold true that is expected to be true at a particular point in a program..
Thats why the program execution is interrupted and the dialog box appears saying Retry, Abort or Ignore.
if you hit ignore, it simply ignores the assertion and continues your program...